# unable to install IBM SSL Certificate with tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, ssl

i generate CSR file and upload

there are cert.pem,cert.cert extension file.i tried to include this file in server.xml file but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat prefers jks format of certificate . SO what you do is you can concatenate the private key and the certificates in the below format sequence

a) Private key (this file you might have got when you generated the CSR)

b) Server certificate

c) Intermediate certificate

d) Root certificate.

Name the file as example.pem

2) Run the below openssl command to create a pfx file

openssl pkcs12 -export -in example.pem  -out certificate.pfx

3) Now, as you have the pfx file, run the below keytool command to get a jks file.

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore certificate.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore certificate.jks -deststoretype jks.

4) Use the certificate.jks file  directives in the server.xml along with its password

5) Restart the tomcat service.